# How to get the anchor from the URL using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, anchor

I have a URL that is like:

```
www.example.com/task1/1.3.html#a_1
```

How can I get the `a_1` anchor value using jQuery and store it as a variable?

Comment: Short: `window.location.hash.substring(1)` or `window.location.hash.split('#').pop();`

Answer (score 218, accepted):

You can use the [`.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) and [`.substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring), like this:

```
var url = "www.aaa.com/task1/1.3.html#a_1";
var hash = url.substring(url.indexOf("#")+1);
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/mpdSD/), if it may not have a `#` in it, do an `if(url.indexOf("#") != -1)` check like this:

```
var url = "www.aaa.com/task1/1.3.html#a_1", idx = url.indexOf("#");
var hash = idx != -1 ? url.substring(idx+1) : "";
```

---

If this is the *current* page URL, you can just use `window.location.hash` to get it, and replace the `#` if you wish.

Comment: Please note: to get the hash value of the main window from inside an iFrame, you must use `window.top.location.hash` instead.

Comment: `url.split("#").pop()`  - Slower but easier.

Answer (score 562):

For **current window**, you can use this:

```
var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
```

To get the hash value of the **main window**, use this:

```
var hash = window.top.location.hash.substring(1);
```

If you have a **string** with an URL/hash, the easiest method is:

```
var url = 'https://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/123/abc#10076097';
var hash = url.split('#').pop();
```

If you're using **jQuery**, use this:

```
var hash = $(location).attr('hash');
```

Comment: Elegant answer. Are there any cases in which this doesn't work?

Comment: shortcut version - `var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);`
because of a JS have both substr/substring functions, they are different, but in this case the same.

Comment: what's the best way of keeping track of changes of this, ie. somebody clicked an inner-page link?

Comment: @RidIculous try this: $(window).on('hashchange',function(){ 
    $('h1').text(location.hash.slice(1));
});

Comment: If the hash value may contain spaces or special characters, you might want to add `hash = hash && decodeURI(hash)` to get the original value

Answer (score 78):

Use

```
window.location.hash
```

to retrieve everything beyond and including the #

Comment: Remember to use `location.hash.slice(1)` if you don't want the hash tag in the final string!

Answer (score 41):

jQuery style:

```
$(location).attr('hash');
```

Comment: not every javascript problem needs to be solved with jquery.

Comment: @doxin I agree but the question is "How to get the anchor from the URL using jQuery?"

Answer (score 12):

You can use the following "trick" to parse *any* valid URL. It takes advantage of the [anchor element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAnchorElement)'s special href-related property, `hash`.

### With jQuery

```
function getHashFromUrl(url){
    return $("<a />").attr("href", url)[0].hash.replace(/^#/, "");
}
getHashFromUrl("www.example.com/task1/1.3.html#a_1"); // a_1
```

### With plain JS

```
function getHashFromUrl(url){
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    a.href = url;
    return a.hash.replace(/^#/, "");
};
getHashFromUrl("www.example.com/task1/1.3.html#a_1"); // a_1
```

Answer (score 3):

If you just have a plain url string (and therefore don't have a hash attribute) you can also use a regular expression:

```
var url = "www.example.com/task1/1.3.html#a_1"  
var anchor = url.match(/#(.*)/)[1]
```

Comment: Need to check that match gets results before accessing second element of it, or this code will error if the url has no anchor.