# CSS- Highlight a div when the id is linked to using an anchor?

Tags: javascript, css, html, anchor, highlight

What I am attempting to do is to highlight a div with a certain id, when It has been referred to by an anchor on another page IE:

User clicks link `href="qw.html#test"`, when the page is loaded, then the div with the `id="test"`
is highlighted so that the user can see it clearly.

I'm sure that I've seen a CSS3 example where a div is highlighted if it was linked to.
Or was it JavaScript?

Answer (score 160, accepted):

You can use the [:target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target#examples) pseudo-class to select an element whose ID exactly matches the "fragment" part of the URL (the part after the # which jumps to a named anchor within the page).

So for example, the following rule would apply to **any** element that you jump to with a URL fragment:

```css
:target {
   background-color: #ffa;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/NGyVL/).

And the following rule would apply to a DIV called `john`, but **only** when the fragment in the current URL is `#john` (the fragment is the same as the ID of the DIV):

```css
div#john:target {
   background-color: #ffa;
}
```

If you click a link within the page which changes only fragment part of the URL, then the element selected by the `:target` pseudo-class will change.

Comment: @DavidThomas, can this be done for *any* target? Or do I have to specify the id each time?

Comment: @DAE: the 'target' is identified by the URL fragment identifier (the `#elementID`), so it can only work for an element that has an `id` and has its `id` in the URL like so: `http://example.com#elementID`

Comment: @DavidThomas actually in the end i tried a:target and it works fine for my purposes :)

Comment: If answer was self contained, then it would be worth an up vote. As is it misses the important part: how to create a target is only on the other site.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in JavaScript. Refer to [How to get the anchor from the URL using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552944/how-to-get-the-anchor-from-the-url-using-jquery) on how to get the anchor from URL and then it can be something simple like

```
document.getElementById(hash).style.backgroundColor="Yellow";
```

Comment: That is helpful thanks but I like to just use CSS if possible. Thanks for the alternative anyways.

Comment: And I could not get this to work when linking within the file (i.e. refreshing the page but with a different anchor) while the CSS style approach does work for m.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript can be used to dynamically add/change the class of the div:

If you have:

```
<div id="test"></div>
```

Javascript function, executed by the click of the anchor:

```
document.getElementById("test").className += " highlighted";
```

Result:

```
<div id="test" class=" highlighted"></div>
```