# Hightlight Anchor ID when visited by an Anchor URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, anchor, highlight

**EDIT:**

Someone mentioned this was possible in CSS so I looked it up and that is exactly what I needed!

**CSS**

> You need to use the :target pseudo-class:
>
> ```
> :target {
>    background-color: #ffa;
> }
> ```
>
> [JS Fiddle demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/NGyVL/)
>
> Thanks David Thomas [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11142257/3492646)

---

**ALSO THANKS MILIND YOUR CODE IS ALSO WHAT I NEEDED**

---

I've been trying to figure this out for a while.

When someone visits my page trough an URL like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/maNR5/show/#second

I want the header element with id second to be highlighted with a background color.

```
<div>

    <h1><a id="first">How can I...</a></h1>    

    <h1><a id="second">...make this...</a></h1>

    <h1><a id="turd">Highlighted when....</a></h1>    

    <h1><a id="furd">Visited by an...</a></h1> 

    <h1><a id="earth">Anchor URL</a></h1>


</div>
```

Is this possible in javascript? Thanks for any tips.

Comment: You could do it with CSS.

Comment: with CSS! can you please explain me how? tHANKS EDIT: found out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 var id=window.location.href.substring(window.location.href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
 $(id).css('background-color','red');
```

Answer (score 4):

Try to use:

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
$('#'+hash).parent().css('background-color','red');
```

Comment: Can you show me an example on jsfiddle? I can't get this one to work. Maybe i'm doing it wrong. Tx

Answer (score 0):

try this.
when ever you click on any of the links change its color.
Indicates that it is visited.

```
$("h1").each(function(a,b){
    $(this).find('a').click(function(){
        console.log(this);
        $(this).css('color','#333399');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I want. I need the part of page that is linked to the anchor link to be highlighted when visited! But thanks anyways!!