# Fire jquery when the hash is video

Tags: javascript, jquery, video

I have a simple question. I want do some javascript. When the url is #video. For example. This is my website: www.website.nl. When the url is www.website.nl/#video. Than i must do what javascript. How can i make that:

A start with this code:

```
$("a[href='http://www.website.nl/#video']"){
            alert("test");
        };
```

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552944/how-to-get-the-anchor-from-the-url-using-jquery It explains how to get the anchor url.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var url = $('a').attr('href');
var hash = url.substring(url.indexOf("#")+1);

if ( hash === 'video' ) {
  alert('test');
}

<a href="http://www.website.nl/#video">a</a>​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EGHuB/9/

Answer (score 0):

You have right selector you, but wrong syntax for block enclosing alert

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HDnnk/3/)**

```
$("a[href='http://www.website.nl/#video']").each(function(){
            alert("test");
});​
```

If you know you have only one element then you do not need each

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HDnnk/4/)**

```
 alert($("a[href='http://www.website.nl/#video']")[0].href);​
```

or

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HDnnk/5/)**

```
alert($("a[href='http://www.website.nl/#video']").attr('href'));​
```