# Can I retrieve the current anchor position?

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to figure this out and I keep riddling myself to nowhere.

I have a blog with all the posts numbered chronologically from 1 to X (class), each page of the blog displays 10 posts, each with a numbered anchor (post1, post2, etc).

I can't figure out how to retrieve the id/class/name of the anchor of the element currently displayed on the screen (where the scrollbar is) if the user didn't get to the anchor by clicking a link.

Can this even be done? I'm trying to code it in JavaScript but I don't know where to start, a nod in the right direction would help a lot.

Comment: Please try this [parsing url method][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552944/how-to-get-the-anchor-from-the-url-using-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the anchor's id/name isn't in the URL then you could try combining a function to get absolute position of elements

```
function pos(e) {
    var o = {left:e.offsetLeft, top:e.offsetTop};
    while (e=e.offsetParent)
        o.left = o.left + e.offsetLeft,
        o.top = o.top + e.offsetTop;
    return o;
}
```

with a loop over `document.getElementsByTagName('a')` (or some other list of nodes you want to check)

and check `window.scrollY <= o.top && o.top <= window.scrollY + window.innerHeight` to find if the `<a>` is in the window.

Answer (score 0):

I would test all anchor links for being visible in the viewport. You'll need to decide which one to pick if more than one is visible.

[How to tell if a DOM element is visible in the current viewport?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123999/how-to-tell-if-a-dom-element-is-visible-in-the-current-viewport)

Comment: Thank you for your help! That link actually cleared up a lot of things for me.