# call jQuery dialog from website url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make something like that:
https://www.easybring.com/#registration

as you can see, "registration" is in a jquery dialog, which can be opened by clicking on regiser button inside the website. Until now i'm good:

```
<a onClick="showDialog({$product['id']});">More Info </a>
```

My Head contains:

```
function showDialog(productID){
    $( "#dialog-modal_"+productID ).dialog({
        width: 770,
        height: 590,
        modal: true,
        open: function(event, ui){
        }
    });
}
```

And of course i have the div:

```
<div id="dialog-modal_{$product['id']}" style="display: none;">
<iframe src="index.php?act=showProduct&id={$product['id']}" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe> 
</div>
```

But what I want to do, is to call that jquery specific dialog, by website url: #registration.

How can i do it?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one should work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
if( window.location.href.indexOf( '#registration' ) != -1 ) {
    showDialog({$product['id']});
}
});
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: And now: is there a simple way to replace #registeration by #product-___ : i think it's gonna be in regex ? and than cal showDialon( id ) ...

Comment: doesnt matter - i successfully did that by javascript split. thanks alot!!

Answer (score 0):

You can handle your url on document load event:

```
$(function() {
    if (window.location.toString().indexOf('#registration') > -1) {
        showDialog({$product['id']});
    }
});
```

Code might not work but I think that idea is clear.

This might help you to work with url string in JS: [How to get the anchor from the URL using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552944/how-to-get-the-anchor-from-the-url-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you call **showDialog()** inside **$(document).ready()**

Something like this

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#dialog-modal").dialog({modal: true});
});
```