# getting parameter from url

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

I have this url `index.html#secondPage?name=the%20second%20page`

I want to get the value of name ("the second page") using javascript and jquery

thanks

Comment: You are trying to get the anchor. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552944/how-to-get-the-anchor-from-the-url-using-jquery

Comment: Hello,you should take the time and search for similar questions here,this question has been asked different times already,you could start here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403888/get-url-parameter-with-jquery

Comment: This may be an answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403888/get-url-parameter-with-jquery

Comment: Those aren't quite duplicates since they all use `location.search` which will be empty in the url the poster is asking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the code from the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values?rq=1). The only difference is that you want to parse the `location.hash` instead of `location.search` so just change that in whichever answer you choose to go with.

You'll also need to use `substr` to delete the leading `#` like:

```
var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
```

Here is the code from my answer to the question I linked to, with the modification:

```
function get_query(){
    var url = location.hash.substr(1);
    var qs = url.substring(url.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for(var i = 0, result = {}; i < qs.length; i++){
        qs[i] = qs[i].split('=');
        result[qs[i][0]] = decodeURIComponent(qs[i][1]);
    }
    return result;
}
```

You can use it like:

```
var secondPage = get_query()['name']; // 'the second page'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like below, It will help you

**Fiddle :** http://jsfiddle.net/RYh7U/144/

**Javascript :**

```
function GetURLValue (sKey) {
  return unescape("index.html#secondPage?name=the%20second%20page".replace(new RegExp("^(?:.*[&\\?]" + escape(sKey).replace(/[\.\+\*]/g, "\\$&") + "(?:\\=([^&]*))?)?.*$", "i"), "$1"));
}

alert(GetURLValue("name"));
```