# How to to get the anchor from Razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

From a MVC4 project, a href uses a link like "/myPage#myAnchor".

How can I get from the View the anchor part of the url? in the above case myAnchor.

Comment: would you like to use jquery?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with some script. Check the bellow link:

[how to get anchor from url string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552944/how-to-get-the-anchor-from-the-url-using-jquery)

If you want to use @ attribute of Razor syntax in your script, just put script inside of view pages to render @ attribute by the application.

Comment: I meant a C# function or property to get the #anchor. I can use an C# custom function but I was asking to get a existing proc.