# Accordion div. Open a specific link from another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, anchor, accordion

The following is in TestPage1.html

```
   <p class ="User"> 
   <a name="H1"></a>HEADING1</p>

   <div class="description" style="display:none">

--CONTENT OF THE PANEL---

   </div>

   <p class ="User">
   <a name="H2"></a>HEADING2 </p>

   <div class="description" style="display:none">

   --CONTENT OF THE PANEL---

    </div>
```

When the user clicks on Heading1 or Heading2, the content collapses/expands.

The following content is in another page (Testpage2.html). So when I click on the link, it is supposed to open the content in HEADING1.

```
    <a href="NAME OF PAGE.HTML#H1">LINK</a>
```

Here is the JQUERY:

```
    $(document).ready(function() { 
    $(".description").hide();   

    $(".User").click(function()  {    
    $(this).next(".description").slideToggle(500);  });  

    $(".User").click(function(event){ 
    window.location.hash=this.hash; 
    }); 

   });
    </script>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the actual error/issue ?

Comment: The issue is when I click on the link from [Testpage2.html], it just goes to the page. It doesn't open the contents in #H1 Heading.

Comment: The click-event is triggered twice in an unknow order, first the slideToggle and then the window.location... (or vice versa)

Comment: You want to load contents from another file when clicking on a header? (but instead it redirects to the other page). Is that the problem?

Comment: I am not trying to load the contents, instead accessing the information within the collapsible DIV from another page. I am used to anchoring HTML links but in this case it doesn't work.

Comment: You will have to read which anchor there is in the url and then decide what to show. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552944/how-to-get-the-anchor-from-the-url-using-jquery . hope it helps!