# External navbar - How to find the current page

Tags: php, html, jquery-mobile

I want a navigation bar on the top of my site. I use a external file for this navbar.

```
<div data-role="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#home">Startseite</a></li>
        <li><a href="#library">Bibliothek</a></li>
        <li><a href="#statistics">Statistik</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

But now I want to set the class `ui-btn-active` and `ui-state-persist` so I know on which page I am currently. So my question is how I do I find out on which page I am currently so I am able to set this class. I also post here one of the pages.

```
<div data-role="page" id="statistics">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Statistik</h1>
        <?php
            include './static/navbar.php';
        ?>
    </div>
    
    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    </div>
</div>
```

I am using a lamp server so I have the ability to use PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The # param in url is a browser parameter, so php can't obtain this (I think). 
You must use javascript to check total url with `document.URL` and post it to a php via ajax.
When php recibe the data you can use this to obtain THE NEXT OF#, the anchor that you want.

```
$foo = parse_url('http://www.example.com/index.php#action', PHP_URL_FRAGMENT);
```

Car read about this here http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

But I think that you can select the buttons only with javascript. Taking the url you can process it and take only after # and add a class to the button that match.
Here are good ino to take anchor [How to get the anchor from the URL using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552944/how-to-get-the-anchor-from-the-url-using-jquery)

Comment: Yea this seems to work. But I will add a parameter to the navbar and send the id to the navbar. That is easier for me. However I'll accept your answer. Thank you for your help, I really appreciate it! :D