# Highlight the element I enter with its id

Tags: jquery, html

I want something that is so close to the thing we have in stackoverflow.
Consider i have a page like this : "myPage.com".
then consider that after a search i want to redirect the user to this page but exactly on the desired element, like this : "myPage.com#123".
As you know the "123" is the id of the element i want the page to scroll to it.
but the thing is that scrolling is not enough. I want to do additional jobs with JQuery and i want to know how can i add event handlers to this. And being more direct, what is this event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way to do that is to check hash on document ready like this:

```js
$(function() {
    // assign value of hash to hash variable
    var hash = window.location.hash;

    // check if hash isn't undefined
    if (hash) {
        // target element with id from hash
        var $where = $(hash);
        // animate scroll to position of element from hash
 $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: parseInt($where.position().top) + 'px' }, 300);
    } else {
        // there is no hash ;-)
 alert('no hash');
    }
});
```

There is also onhashchange event:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onhashchange

Comment: This will be good at the page load but the thing is i will have an in page search! which will link to an id in the same page. this answer is good and i can handle the things manually but if is there any even of being notified of a hash, it will be better. thanks.

Comment: Glad I could help ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can add an event listener to the load event. and then [get the Anchor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552944/how-to-get-the-anchor-from-the-url-using-jquery) (the #123) and then do whethever you want with it.

For the scrolling, the #123 is enough for the browser to understand what you want.