# Given a URL how can I find the anchor HTML anchor tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working with a JavaScript framework that performs a callback when a link is clicked. The method includes the full path of the URL that was selected.

Given the URL, is there a JavaScript (or jQuery) selector to target the HTML anchor tag that was clicked?

Comment: Your approach seems wrong. Searching anchor by URL is not foolproof, e.g. there could be multiple anchors with that URL. You should listen for a `click` event instead.

Comment: See also this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552944/how-to-get-the-anchor-from-the-url-using-jquery

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery you can use the attribute selector, which goes like `[attribute='attribute value']`

```
$('a').click(function () {
  var $this = $(this);
  var href = $this.attr('href');
  var selector = "a[href='" + href + "']";
  console.log(this, $(selector));
});
```

Comment: do watch out for relative links with that method; the browser launders them to full urls as they are used, so matching might not be 100%...

Answer (score 0):

This one should print, specific clicked tag...

```
$('a').on('click', function(){
   var attr = $(this).attr('href');
   console.log(attr);
})
```