# Laravel 5.2 catch Anchior name from URL

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5

I am developing an Laravel 5.2 and I wondering if I can catch an anchor present on the url like:

```
http://www.domain.com/public/folder/5#anchor_name
```

I need to read this from url to collapse or not a Toggle Panel. Do you think is this possible?

I know I can do this from [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552944/how-to-get-the-anchor-from-the-url-using-jquery), but I need to know if I can manage this from the controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't. The anchor part isn't sent to the server by the browser in the first place, so the server can't see it. You'll have to use JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your fast response. I will use JS then to send it to the server.